# Do all vaishnavite sects impose diet restrictions?

Tags: vaishnavism, food

In general Hindus tend to be vegetarian or quasi-vegetarian.  In addition there is the "satvik food" theory.  What diet restrictions do different vaishnavite sects apply to their followers?